# Wait until DB query is done

Tags: javascript, sqlite, koa

I'm pretty sure my issue is not directly related to the use of Koa or SQLite3, but more to the general use of JavaScript.

I have the following `server.js`:

```
var http = require('http');
var koa = require('koa');
var route = require('koa-route');
var app = koa();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var dbFile = 'coc.db';
var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);

var members = [];

var printMembers = function(name){

        db.each(query, [name], function(err, row){
            members.push(row);
        });

    return members;

}


app.use(route.get('/', index));


function *index() {

    this.body = printMembers("name");

}


app.listen(8008);
console.log('Koa listening on port 8008');
```

When I start the server and visit `localhost:8008` for the first time, I only get an empty Array (`[]`) as a response. This is the content of the variable `members`. When I then reload I get, as expected, my SQLite query results.

The reason is probably because my query takes longer than the script is executed. Of course, the second time `members` is filled. But with the results of the query of the first time!
Also `var members = []` should be declared within `printMembers`.

In my opinion I need something to make sure, that `index()` is waiting until `db.each()` is done. But how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Update: These days you'd use Koa 2.x which uses promises and first-class async/await in place of the co/yield example in this answer.)

Since the core abstraction in Koa 1.x is to use generators for control flow
in routes, you must use `yield` to wait for something to finish.

Koa uses https://github.com/tj/co under the hood, so when trying to
interop with libraries that aren't built for Koa, as a Koa developer you
basically just need to figure out how you can modify/wrap asynchronous libraries
so that you can `yield` them inside your route.

You can basically `yield` generators and promises.

The most general-purpose tool for the job is to wrap a function with
a Promise. When creating a Promise (`new Promise(fn)`), you must pass it a
function `fn` that takes two functions as arguments: `resolve` and `reject`.

You can often find Co-specific libraries where someone has already wrapped a popular
library in a way that lets you `yield` its functions/methods.

For example, check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-sqlite3. (I have no idea how good it is, but fortunately it's easy to wrap stuff yourself if it turns out to be no good)

Alternatively, there are libraries that can take a callback-style module (i.e. most Node modules)
and wrap it so that it returns promises which you can `yield`.

For example, [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) has a [promisifyAll](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) function that does this, though to be honest I've never used bluebird.

```
// (Untested)
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = Promise.promisifyAll(new sqlite3.Database(':memory:'));

function* printMembers(name) {
  var query = '...';
  return yield db.allAsync(query, [name]);
}

function* index() {
  // promisifyAll adds an {fnName}Async version of all the functions
  // to the module you call it on, so now we can call `allAsync`.

  var members = yield db.allAsync(query, ['name']);
  // or
  var members = yield printMembers('name');

  this.body = members;
}
```

But I'll give you some Promise-wrapping examples since it's such an essential
tool to have in your kit.

Here I rewrite your `printMembers` function to return a Promise which you
can then `yield` from your route:

```
var printMembers = function(name) {
  var query = '...';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var rows = [];
    db.each(query, [name], function(err, row){
      if (err) return reject(err);
      rows.push(row);
    });
    resolve(rows);
  });
}
```

Though note that sqlite3 has a [Database#all](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback)
function that returns all the rows to you at once so you don't have to manually build an array:

```
var printMembers = function(name) {
  var query = '...';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.all(query, [name], function(err, rows){
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(rows);
    });
  });
}
```

Now, here's what your route would look like:

```
function *index() {
  var members = yield printMembers('name');
  this.body = members;
}
```

If the promise hits that `reject(err)` path, then the promise is put in a rejected
state and will throw the error which you can try/catch if you want where you yield
the promise.

If the promise hits that `resolve(members)` path, then that's what's yielded
and assigned to the `members` variable.

Comment: Wow, this was a perfect answer! a) Now I know which lego brick of JS I was missing, b) you gave multiple approaches for a solution and c) you even gave a working example. Thank you so much! Its just hard when you have a problem but don't know what to search for!